# porting an existing fortran code with mpi to hybrid mpi openmp

Tags: openmp

I have an existing fortran code which is compiled using mpif90. It compiles and runs successfully. But when i introduce -fopenmp option mpif90 compiler compiles the code successfully but the program fails to run to completion. It abruptly quits before entering a subroutine. Seems like the stack is full so the program quits abruptly. The manpages say that -fopenmp will allocate arrays on stack and it is like using -frecursive flag. How do I proceed with this problem and what -frecursive flag?

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the stack for both the master thread (on linux that would be with the limit or ulimit command) and for the slave threads (if you are using OpenMP V3.0, that would be through the environment variable OMP_STACKSIZE).

Comment: I tried setting the stack size but that didn't help. I went upto a maximum of 500mb

Comment: Another strange problem i found was when i run the program using 1 mpi task the program fails. But when i tried to use 2 mpi tasks the programs runs to completion.